# Prevent terminal close

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to prevent terminal closing in Visual Studio Code C/C++ when program terminates. I am writing a program that is independent of operating system (don't even use stdio.h I have my own implementation) so tweeks like `getchar()` before return won't work.

I'm wondering if there exists a way to do this from `launch.json` or other settings.